# UIAccessibility.isGrayscaleEnabled doesn't work

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, uiaccessibility

I was in the process of creating an application in which I use information about Color Filters and more specifically Grayscale. And property UIAccessibility.isGrayscaleEnabled stopped working. I created a simple view in which I check whether the information about bold or color invert works. And it works. Only for grayscale it doesn't. What might be the issue here?

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
           Text("Bold: " + String(UIAccessibility.isBoldTextEnabled))
           Text("Grayscale: " + String(UIAccessibility.isGrayscaleEnabled))
           Text("Invert: " + String(UIAccessibility.isInvertColorsEnabled))
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I am a beginner and would appreciate any advice ☺️ Thanks!